# Get email id's of friends of the person who has logged in via facebook connect

Tags: php, email, facebook

I'm thinking of making something like "find friend's" in facebook for my site. For which i need to get email id's of all the friends of the user who logs in my site using facebook connect. Can i get them via facebook connect.

Answer (score 0):

A Facebook user's email address is not public information. You cannot access this without permission.

The friend feed may return names, profile photos, UID

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/